# Background-image cuts off on top, left, and right points of a CSS circle

Tags: html, css, background-repeat, css-shapes

I am having a problem with an image getting cut off on the top, left, and right points of my div. When I don't set `background-repeat: no-repeat;` the image repeats on only those three points which makes an awkward feel to it.

```
----^----
<------->
----X----
```

The 'X' is the point that is not effected by this.

When I set `background-repeat: no-repeat;` it cuts those points off completely and leaves a box like shape rather then a circle.

*The top is the most noticeable point out of the three*

**Tested in Chomre, Firefox, and Safari.**

Here is the css:

```
#picFrame {
    height: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 15%;
    left: 50%;
    background-image: url("http://jpowell43.mydevryportfolio.com/me.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
    /*background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/ygFKD/)

Comment: what happens if you make the image 10px higher and 20px wider?

Comment: Using a pseudo element for the border may be a possible workaround: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygFKD/2/)

Comment: That is the biggest image size I have at the moment. I can give this a try and let you know.

Comment: @Adrift that is indeed a work around, do you think this is due to the box-sizing?

Comment: The border isn't supposed to cover the content. I actually think those three sides are the way it's supposed to work. The image overflow is what's preventing the issue at the bottom. If your image were square, the bottom would have the same issue. You need to move the image and enlarge it using a percent to make it go underneath the border.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `background-position: -10px center` to account for the `10px` border, and make the `background-size: 110%;` so it expands horizontally to be covered by the border. Then set `background-repeat: no-repeat`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ygFKD/5/)**

Comment: This is a solid work around! Thank you for all of the help, do you think this is due to the box-sizing?

Comment: No. Read my comment above. This is how divs actually work. The border doesn't cover any content and isn't supposed to. Box-sizing only affects how width and height are calculated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to adjust the image `width` and `height`

http://jsfiddle.net/ygFKD/3/